# Database design for awards system - Count on the fly or use separate/join table?

Tags: database-design, scalability, database-performance

The following scenario could be compared to StackExchange reputation system. I'm wondering which would be the best approach in terms of performance and scalability.

Scenario: I have a gaming site and I need to give medal awards for users. Each medal obviously having it's own requirements. Examples: playing certain number of matches; winning streaks; Top 1 score of a match; etc.

Option 1: Store records on a join table (users_medals) if conditions are met at the moment a new match is registered. This would be simpler and faster at first, but it'd be hard to track future changes to conditions (for instance: increasing the number of victories required for certain medal).

Option 2: Don't store any relation and perform all calculations every time user is browsing an user profile. It would handle changes to conditions easily, but the more users and medals, the slowest it would be to show info for an user or worse, a list of users.

Comment: Option3: run a sceduled task to detect new medals and persist the results.

Comment: about option 2 - on changing conditions, would you really take away well-earned medals?

Comment: Well yes, in some cases I would have to. A common reason for changing criteria would be to balance things out. It'd be unfair to the new users if the old users had more medals because the requirements were easier before the new ones joined. But yeah, it should have at least an option to keep old awards when intended.

Comment: @MitchWheat could you please expand on that? Is this approach more common on similar systems like stackoverflow for example? One advantage I see there if compared to option1 is that I'd have more control over when the changes on criteria (and the consequent changes on earned medals) would take effect. But I'd still like the users to see what they've earned as soon as match results are posted. I guess in that case I should detect and store awards normally at match post and let the scheduled task correct them later if applicable (criteria changed).

Answer (score 0):

First of all I agree with miraculixx that already earned medals should stay with the user. Therefore you should persist the earned medals with the user record in either a joint table or use an approach I use for speeding apps dramatically:

1. Have a table storing medal names + criteria to reach it
2. Store the Id's of earned medals in a column on the user record (comma separated, Json, Hstore, XML...) - that's slightly denormalized but will increase lookup speed dramatically.
3. Maybe add another table with every event leading to new medals as you might want to give users the option to see their history, compare speed in which people reach their goals and so on.

I would definitely not go with your route 2 as you will run into really bad performance problems as your user base increases.

Now when a user looks at their profile your app will iterate over the column with the Id's of medals and pull them from your small table with maybe a couple dozens of different medals and show them (milliseconds), rather than calculating what medals he has earned (very slow in large tables). Your users can pull history records, you can create statistics and so on.

In case you change criteria to reach certain goals existing users who reached it with previous criteria keep their medals and new users need to fulfill the new criteria. If you don't want this take the reached medals away (people would get really mad;-))

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best approach to provide scalable but fast solution is to cache calculated values. I would decompose stuff into multiple tables (or whatever it's called in any nosql db) but calculate changes and persist them - its important to be fast. The only user related drawback is certain inconsistency which is wrapped into term [eventual consistency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency). Depends on what your user will tolerates.

I think the best example how to think about this kind of problem and solution is to study how someone would design twitter solution using redis, see http://redis.io/topics/twitter-clone